# Refreshing the content of BootStrap Popover

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to refresh the content of the popover. I know the content gets updated when i click the button, however, its not showing on the already opened popover..

```
$('#popOverPr')
    .popover(
        {
            animate : false,
            html : true,
            offset : 10,
            placement : 'bottom',
            template : '<div class="popover popOverProgress" "><div class="arrow" style="left:80%";></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title" style="display:none;"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>',
            content : function() {
                                        return $('#popOverPr-content').html();
                                }
$('#popOverPr').popover('show');


$('.popoverButton').on('click', function() {

//if(........)
    $('#popOverPauseText').text("Resume");
// else
    $('#popOverPauseText').text("Start");

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy the popover, recreate a new one with different content